# how to write $X_1 X_2 + X_2 X_3$ in the form of Summation?

Tags: summation

i am trying to write this formula

$$X_1 X_2 + X_2 X_3$$

in the form of summation.

is this right?

$$\sum_{i < j} X_i X_j, \quad i,j \in\{1,2,3\}$$

if not, please give a right one.

Comment: Or $X_i X_{i+1}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum you have given is actually equal to $$X_1X_2+X_1X_3+X_2X_3$$
As noted in a comment, the sum you want is $$\sum_{i=1}^2X_iX_{i+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your method is not correct (as saulspatz wrote). You can alternatively write the expression as a [cyclic sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215016/meaning-of-sum-textcyclic) which cycles over ${x_1, x_2, x_3}$:

$$\left(\sum_{x_1, x_2, x_3} x_1x_2 \right) - x_3x_1$$.